# How to Know an IP Address is Local or not on Linux Server

Tags: c++, linux, networking, ip

We are developing a Server software on Linux using C/C++, this software will limit the download rate for those requests which are from the Internet, but for those from local machines (intranet) it won't set any limit.

The problem is how to judge an IP address is local or not, is it possible to do it through c/c++ by reading some network number settings (maybe from router?)?

**UPDATE**
When I say local ip, I mean it is from within the company. For example, suppose the company has three subnets (this company only has a DSL link to the internet), they are 10.123.1.xxx, 172.16.1.xxx and 192.168.1.xxx, then all ip addresses from these three subnets should be considered as local address.

Comment: It depends a bit on your definition of "local". Do you mean "the same subnet" (in which case, look at the subnet mask), or "within the company" (in which case, test for the range of IP addresses you own); or maybe "behind the firewall" (in which case you might have address starting with `192.168`, `10.0`, etc…)

Comment: Please clarify: do you know what these numbers are, and do you want to filter against them - or do you want to know how to figure out that `192.168` etc are the local numbers to filter against?

Comment: @Floris the latter one. we want to know how to figure out a request (via the socket connection we know its ip address) is from inside the company or outside the company. And as a software which is supposed to be used by customer company's administor, it doesn't directly know any details about the network number and mask in customer's company.

Answer (score 1):

The private address ranges are:

```
10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (10/8 prefix)

172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (172.16/12 prefix)

192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

You might also want to filter out link-local addresses (169.254/16)

You could then parse the ip address in your code(to get the addresses you could use avahi or something similiar and save all the addresses to a file and then parse each address individually)and check it matches these addresses. If it does not then limit its connection

**Edit**

You could also look into using the [getifaddrs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) function that will list local addresses

Comment: seems getifaddrs only lists the ip addresses the Server machine has, it won't list the network number what is inside the compnay. Am I wrong?

Comment: Possibly I only found it in a quick google search and haven't used it personally. I use avahi to display all connected network devices. If you run avahi -alrt on your local machine it will list all the machines on any connected networks. You can then use sed/grep or something to filter this into a form which you can parse through your c++ code which you can then check begins with 10.123.1.x etc. There is no really easy way AFAIK to do it directly in C++

Comment: I'd add 127.0.0.1 since loopback is local

Answer (score 0):

If you run a `traceroute` on the IP address of the machine requesting a connection, you should be able to see whether the route takes you through the "gateway outside the company" (typically your ISP). A simple example in my house would be the Time Warner gateway that my internal router connects to. If the route to the client does not go through the ISP (as you mentioned, you have a DSL link; so the IP address of the DSL endpoint should be known), then it's an internal request. This doesn't require you to know the full map of IP addresses inside the company - you can assume your routers have it figured out.

To get this information you can run a system command from inside your program and parse the response.

To start with, run it from the command line (with a known "internal" and "external" IP address), and look at the difference. If you need further help after that, please update your question with the information you gathered.